# CL_OUT_OF_RESOURCES on clEnqueueAcquireGLObjects

Tags: c++, opengl, opencl

After rearranging some OpenCL/GL interop code it stopped working and gave the error in the title.

I already read many threads that discussed this issue and blamed the (nvidia) driver for it. But as the code ran before this should not be my problem.

**Code**

As I already said I have too much code to post all of it. Also I am not able to reproduce the behaviour in minimal examples so far, so I am going to describe most of the program in pseudo code and parts in excerpts from my real code.

I use Qt, therefore following functions are all members of my subclass of QGLWidget:

```
void initializeGL()
{
    glewInit();

    cl::Platform::get(&clPlatforms);
    cl_context_properties props[] = {
        CL_GL_CONTEXT_KHR, (cl_context_properties)glXGetCurrentContext(),
        CL_GLX_DISPLAY_KHR, (cl_context_properties)glXGetCurrentDisplay(),
        CL_CONTEXT_PLATFORM, (cl_context_properties)clPlatforms[0](),
        0
    };
    clContext = cl::Context(CL_DEVICE_TYPE_GPU, props, cl_notify, &err);
    std::vector<cl::Device> devices = clContext.getInfo<CL_CONTEXT_DEVICES>();
    clDevice = devices[0];
    clQueue = cl::CommandQueue(clContext, clDevice, 0, 0);
    clProgram = cl::Program(context, sources);
    clProgram.build();    
    clKernel = cl::Kernel(clProgram, "main");
    glGenBuffers(1, &vbo);
    glBindBuffers(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, bufferSize, buffer, GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);
    glBindBuffers(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
    vboBuffer = cl::BufferGL(clContext, CL_MEM_READ_WRITE, vbo);
    clKernel.setArg(0, vboBuffer);
}

void paintGL()
{
    simulate();
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    //camera transformations ...
    glEnable(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo);
    glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, sizeof(cl_float3), 0);
    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 3 * numTriangles, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, triangleIdicesArray);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
}

void simulate()
{
    std::vector<cl::Memory> sharedObjects;
    sharedObjects.push_back(vboBuffer);
    clQueue.enqueueAcquireGLObjects(&sharedObjects); //this triggers the error
    clQueue.enqueNDRangKernel(clKernel, cl::NullRange, cl::NDRangle(numVertices), cl::NullRange);
    clQueue.enqueueReleaseGLObjects(&sharedObjects);
}
```

---

Some further investigation about [glEnqueueAcquireGLObjects](http://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/sdk/1.1/docs/man/xhtml/clEnqueueAcquireGLObjects.html) turned up (in the notes section):

> Prior to calling clEnqueueAcquireGLObjects, the application must ensure that any pending GL operations which access the objects specified in mem_objects have completed. This may be accomplished portably by issuing and waiting for completion of a glFinish command on all GL contexts with pending references to these objects.

Adding a finish on the OpenCL command queue before and after the acquire/release got me rid of these errors.

As with other errors I find the error code misleading and the notify function did not add any valuable information (it said the same).

Comment: Can we see the code that's throwing the error?

Comment: @GuntherFox: I could give it to you but it is very big (~10k lines of code). I have no minimal example yet. Also I just intended to deliver question and (my) solution without going much into detail about my code as it seems a common problem. (I must admit I just post this here to find it later on when I hit the same problem again and forgot the solution :)

Comment: I had this error before. In my case (intel implementation) the problem was that the GL context must be made current before calling clAcquireGLObjects. (It is a bug, the CL specs doesn't mention this).

Comment: @sbabbi: Which is only necessary if you use multiple threads? You could add this as an answer too, to create a (check-)list of possible causes.

Comment: @Nobody: "*I have no minimal example yet.*" Then make one. We can't magically know what it is you're doing that caused this problem.

Comment: @NicolBolas: I have added some code. I tried to make it as short as possible but contain all relevant parts.